# HTML/CSS table display layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to layout the header of my webpage as follows

```
Image1 (30%)   |  Image2 (centered, 30%)   |   Some multiline texts (40%)
```

I was able to use html `<table>` tag to get what I want:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr style="width:100%;">
    <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;"><img src="logo1.png"></td>
    <td style="width:30%; text-align:center;"><img src="logo2.jpg"></td>
    <td style="width:40%; text-align:center;"><p>
      A multiline paragraph<br>
      that is placed on the right<br>
      and has its texts centered.
    </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: img]

But I understand that the `<table>` tag is used for define tabular data, not for layout job like this. I am wondering what is "ideological" way of getting the same layout as above without using HTML `<table>`, but maybe the CSS `display-table`?

Thanks a lot!

---

Stuff I tried that does not work:

(1) Use `<div>`:

```
<header>
  <div style="width:30%; text-align:left;"><img src="logo1.png"></div>
  <div style="width:30%; text-align:center;"><img src="logo2.jpg"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; text-align:center;"><p>
    A multiline paragraph<br>
    that is placed on the right<br>
    and has its texts centered.
  </p></div>
</header>
```

[image: img-div]

(2) Use `<span>` (equivalent to `<div style="display:inline;">`)

```
<header>
  <span style="width:30%; text-align:left;"><img src="logo1.png"></span>
  <span style="width:30%; text-align:center;"><img src="logo2.jpg"></span>
  <span style="width:40%; text-align:center;"><p>
    A multiline paragraph<br>
    that is placed on the right<br>
    and has its texts centered.
  </p></span>
</header>
```

[image: img-span]

Comment: How about putting them in a `div` width:100% and then give the images width:30% and the `p` width:40%?

Comment: @Jonathan Tried that, it will add new line between different `<div>`s, but I want them to be in the same line.

Comment: @Billy Doesn't work either. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `div` and apply `display: table-cell`.

[See example (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/b8c4L0vx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid system by twitter bootstrap as found on their docs
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/css/#grid

Sample code:

```
<div class = "row">
<div class="col-md-4"> Put you first oolumn code here <div/>
<div class="col-md-4"> Put you   second column code here <div/>
<div class="col-md-4"> Put you third column code here <div/>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take 1% or 2% off each span, then display inline, margins etc. are making it more than 100%

```css
header span{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<header>
  <span style="width:28%; text-align:left;"><img src="logo1.png"></span>
  <span style="width:28%; text-align:center;"><img src="logo2.jpg"></span>
  <span style="width:40%; text-align:center;"><p>
    A multiline paragraph<br>
    that is placed on the right<br>
    and has its texts centered.
  </p></span>
</header>
```